# Return duplicate row as one SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am  starting learn SQL and I found a couple of excercise question which I want to solve. You can check question here in picture belowe.

[image]

So far as I see from the table Employee with Id 2 "Lloyd" is repeted 2 times which you can also see in table Payments.
Right now I want to SUM this two record and show as one result.
SO far what I did

```
SELECT p.Amount,
        e.Name  
 FROM Employee e 
 INNER JOIN Payments p
 ON e.EmployeeId = p.Id
```

So far what I get as output result

```
1000    Daniel
2000    Lloyd
300     Patrick
1400    Lloyd
```

So Employee "Lloyd" is repeted 2x times and I want to SUM this two reusult as one (2000+1400) = 3400.
Anyone who can guide me and tell me how to solve this I would be very thankfull ?

**UPDATE**

```
SELECT p.Amount,
        e.Name  
 FROM Employee e 
 LEFT JOIN Payments p
 ON e.EmployeeId = p.Id
 GROUP BY e.Name
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: In the query that you have written, try to use group by and join.
The other solution would be to use PARTITION Syntax . 
If you are unable to solve it, comment below and I'll add the exact query

Comment: @InderPreet When I use LEFT JOIN and GroupBy I  get error. I update my question. Please take a look. 
Here is the error message which I get
`Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column 'Payments.Amount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: but why has Lloyd 2 empoyee_ids at all?

Comment: @nbk I have no idea really man. I found this question from InterviewProcess and I think this is trick question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a aggregation function in your case SUM

```
SELECT SUM(p.Amount),
        e.Name  
 FROM Employee e 
 LEFT JOIN Payments p
 ON e.EmployeeId = p.Id
 GROUP BY e.Name
```

As Anthony says.

A better solution would be

```
SELECT SUM(p.Amount),
       e.EmployeeId,
       e.Name  
 FROM Employee e 
 LEFT JOIN Payments p
 ON e.EmployeeId = p.Id
 GROUP BY e.EmployeeId,e.Name
```

because both Lloyds are probably different people,and so must their salaries be summerized in different accounts

Comment: You should group by id too. In case the name is not unique you would group different people together.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek in my comment i asked, as much but in the question he wants 3400 so no  GROUP BY ID

Comment: The OP is clearly confused, the fact he joins payment id on employee id indicates he has no idea what he is doing. I just wanted to point out, that when two people happen to have the same name, it does not mean they are not the same person.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek please read the question he copied it from somehwhere and wants the summ for Lloydm, the diffret id as mentioned in my comment doesn't mind him at all, so for the sake of the question, no GROUP By id is needed

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should make clear what you are looking at. Every table has an id, that uniquely identifies every row. For `Employee` table it is `EmployeeId` column and for `Payments` table it is just `Id` column. In `Payments` table there is another column `EmployeeId` that indicates, to whom the payment was paid. For example, the Bonus was paid to employee with id 1, that is Daniel. You should join the two tables on this column. There is another thing, there are two different people who happen to have the same name - Lloyd. Such things do happen in real life. They have different `EmployeeId` so they are different. You can join and group the tables, you would get

```
SELECT e.Name, SUM(p.Amount) as SumAmount
FROM Employee e 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Payments p
ON e.EmployeeId = p.EmployeeId
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId, e.Name
```

but imagine the employee has 20 columns. You would have to group by 20 columns. In fact there is no need for that. Do just what you need, calculate the sum for every person

```
SELECT 
  e.Name,
  (SELECT SUM(p.Amount) 
   FROM Payments p 
   WHERE p.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId
  ) as SumAmount
FROM Employee e
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select e.Name, Sum(p.Amount) from Employee e inner join Payment p on
e.EmployeeId = p.EmployeeId group by e.Name
```

This should work for you.
I have used inner join to showcase only those record which have data in payments table. I have grouped the dataset on the basis of name and have used aggregation function to showcase the Amount